# How to delete subarray from array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have multidimensional array and I need to delete one sub array how can I do it without creating another array and copying values?

```
$myarray 
          [one]   a->1 b->2 c->4
          [two]   a->5  b->8
          [three] a->44 b->55 c->66
```

I need to remove two `$myarray['two']`

Comment: http://in.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php#99885

Check out.

Answer (score 6):

Try unsetting it, e.g.

```
unset($myarray['two']);
```

Answer (score 1):

`unset($myarray['one'])` should work